How to get the tensorflow.js model predictions percentage in float
I am following on the codelabs of TensorFlow.js — Handwritten digit recognition with CNNs

The screenshot above, shows the prediction as a float, but when I am calling
const predict = this.model?.predict(testxs);

The screenshot below shows the output of predict.print() and predict.dataSync(). It is returning the value similar to True Label.

How do I get the prediction value?
